# Accepting an answer on a migrated question

Tags: support, user-accounts, migration

My question, [Why is bash everywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628750/why-is-bash-everywhere) was migrated to [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/61727/why-is-bash-everywhere) and there is a really good answer there that I would like to accept.

But I seem to have lost control over the question. Is there some way to associate my account with this migrated question so I can accept an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. create a SU account using your OpenID
2. associate your SO account to your SU account (in the 'accounts' tab of your user profile)
3. flag the SU question that is "yours" (that was yours on SO) and ask the moderator to associate it with your account.

You could do the same here on metaSO to get ownership of this question as well. :)

Comment: Associating accounts should automatically associate the question as well.

Comment: @Brad: ok, I wasn't sure if the a question owned by "unknown (google)" would be correctly picked up.

Comment: Actually, unless I've simply missed the option, "we" don't have a button to associate phantom account; we can only merge active accounts.

Comment: thanks - have now done so and accepted answer