# pre-registration question was migrated, how to accept answer?

Tags: support, new-users, user-accounts, migrated-questions

I asked a question on ServerFault (where I am not registered), and it was migrated to SuperUser. Now I want to accept the closest-to-true answer I got, but I can't -- it does not belong to my SuperUser account. I don't have enough SU reputation to even ask this meta question on meta.su.com (I did get 2 points for editing my question).

There is a question here that seems exactly about the same situation ( [Accepting an answer on a migrated question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27506/accepting-an-answer-on-a-migrated-question)) but I don't see how to apply the answer. In detail, I don't see any option to "flag" a question or to "associate" accounts (I've used the same email address in pre-registration questions and answers, and in registration using StackExchange OpenID; are the accounts already associated?).

My (original) question is https://serverfault.com/questions/368634/how-to-fix-very-high-w-await-on-linux-desktop?noredirect=1

Comment: Have you tried to create an account on Super User yet?

Comment: I have an account, but it doesn't own the question; I edited this question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've associated the question with your account. It should now be possible to accept an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted the answer now.