# Can this question have an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, migration

While on stackoverflow I saw [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412915/will-i-ever-earn-a-student-badge?noredirect=1) which was definitely more of a meta issue. While looking at the question, it was migrated. It is now [here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210315/will-i-ever-earn-a-student-badge).

However, this is kind of an interesting situation. The user is relatively new and did not have a meta account. As a result, there was no account tied to the question when it was migrated to meta. Is it destined to be spend eternity with an unaccepted answer?

When this happens should a new account be offered to the OP so the post can be linked as was requested in a [similar situation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27506/accepting-an-answer-on-a-migrated-question)?

Comment: I'm not sure about *automatically* creating an account. How about a dialog/notification for that user along the lines of, "Your question got migrated to X, would you like to create/link an account?"

Comment: My personal experience is that questions that get asked off-site are rarely sophisticated enough to *need* an accepted answer. And if the OP creates and account afterwards, the question will be reconnected anyway, won't it? I always thought it was

Comment: No, accounts should not be created automatically. Keep in mind that we're talking about an entirely different site in this case. And sites creating accounts for me without my permission would certainly not make me happy. @Pëkka yep, that will indeed happen.

Comment: @GenericHolidayName - Automated account creation could definitely be a little clunky or unsightly. I like the notification idea.

Comment: As far as I know if he will ever create meta account with the same openid, he will be owner of this question. I think I remember seeing this happening. But maybe I'm mistaken? It's late here...

Comment: Related: [After migrating a question, is my account created forcefully?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126095/after-migrating-a-question-is-my-account-created-forcefully), [Auto-create user account on migration of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84657/auto-create-user-account-on-migration-of-questions), [Remind new users to create/associate accounts if a question has been migrated to a site on which the user does not have an account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148761/remind-new-users-to-create-associate-accounts-if-a-question-has-been-migrated-to)

Comment: Looks like the OP made an account on meta, the question was then attached to the OP's account and normal service resumes

Comment: Caching. It's always caching. :)